# pylightxl - xlsx file doesn't display newlines until after I click into the cell

Tags: python, excel

I have new lines working without issue, but the problem is they don't render until the cell is clicked. See:

https://youtu.be/DP1OeikETHg

Here is the code snippet writing the above:

```
db = xl.Database()
for ip_address, inventory in device_inventories.items():
    logging.info("Processing " + ip_address)
    db.add_ws(ip_address, {'A1': {'v': 10, 'f': '', 's': ''}, 'A2': {'v': 20, 'f': '', 's': ''}})  # TODO - I need to fix this
    x = 1
    for subsystem, items in inventory.items():
        y = 1
        db.ws(ip_address).update_index(row=y, col=x, val=subsystem)
        logging.debug("Processing " + subsystem)
        for device, values in items.items():
            y = y + 1
            string = ""
            for key, value in values.items():
                string = string + key + ": " + str(value) + "\n"
            db.ws(ip_address).update_index(row=y, col=x, val=string)
        x = x + 1
xl.writexl(db, 'updated.xlsx')
```

I've tried swapping it out with `\r\n` and all that does is double space everything which tells me Excel isn't doing something like adding the `\r` in the background. At this point I'm not even sure it's a problem in code or if there's just a knob I can hit on Excel that says, "Render this please."

Answer (score 0):

thanks for posting this. You are correct, it is not a bug in the code it is however a limitation of pylightxl. One of the key aspects of pylightxl is to keep it minimal and focus on the read/write of cells, therefore cell styles are currently not supported. As you discovered, the data is correct but you need to have excel render it for you when you open it.

For completeness for those that are curious. Here is the difference between a cell written with pylightxl versus a cell rendered (shown below).

Cell A1 is written with pylightxl, and cell A2 is rendered by excel. Notice that cell A2 has a s="1" that is a style tag that renders the new lines properly. Both are correctly referencing keyvalue=0 that is "this\n\is\nmulti-lined\n"

[image]